SwiftUI Sheet embedded in a ViewController does not slide away with VC in iOS16
In iOS17, I have the expected result:
When popping the ViewController (SecondVC), the sheet goes away together with it.

In iOS 16 however, the sheet stays in place and dismisses after the VC dismiss animation finished.

Code of the relevant VC with the SwiftUI view with the sheet:
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.installSecondView()
    }

    private func installSecondView() {
        let demoView = SecondView()
        let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: demoView)
        self.addChild(hostingVC)
        if let hostingVCview = hostingVC.view {
            self.view.addSubview(hostingVCview)
            self.view.backgroundColor = .purple
            hostingVCview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            hostingVCview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingVCview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingVCview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingVCview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {

    @State private var isShiftSheetPresented = true
    @State private var selectedDetent: PresentationDetent = .fraction(0.4)

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Second View")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isShiftSheetPresented, content: {
            Text("Sheet content")
                .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.2), .fraction(0.3), .fraction(0.4), .large], selection: self.$selectedDetent)
                .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
                .backport.interactiveDismissDisabled()
                .backport.undimSheetBackground()
                .backport.presentationCornerRadius(32)
        })
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.orange)
    }
}


The first view controller that pushes the second VC
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class DemoVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.installDemoView()
    }

    private func installDemoView() {
        let rootView = DemoView(pushButtonAction: self.pushBtnAction)
        let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        self.addChild(hostingVC)
        if let hostingView = hostingVC.view {
            self.view.addSubview(hostingView)
            self.view.backgroundColor = .purple
            hostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            hostingView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            hostingVC.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
    }

    private func pushBtnAction() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondVC(), animated: true)
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {

    private let pushButtonAction: () -> Void

    init(pushButtonAction: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.pushButtonAction = pushButtonAction
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            self.pushButtonAction()
        } label: {
            Text("Push a VC with a sheet")
        }

    }
}


How can I achieve that the sheet is moving away with the VC exactly like the iOS17 behaviour?
